# Values from multiselect attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, product, attributes, multiselect-attribute

I have this code to get values from select/multiselect attributes

```
<?php
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
$themeColor = $attributes['theme_color']->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
echo $themeColor;
?>
```

But it works only for select. When I'm pointing it to multiselect attribute it show nothing.

Comment: Try this: `$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);`

Answer (score 1):

To be more descriptive,

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_product -> getThemeColor(); //this will return the attribute values separated by comma
$_product -> getAttributeText('theme_color'); //this will return the labels of the options separated by comma.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$_product->getAttributeText('theme_color');
```

Comment: No - it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the value(s) of the multiselect attribute for a given product by using the following code:

```
$attribute_value = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

If however you want to get all possible options for a given mutli-select attribute use this code:

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','attribute_code_here');

$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);

$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```